# How is the volume control popup in Android realised?

Tags: android, popup, controls, volume

I want to realise an Android application that shows an always in foreground popup (even in front of the call screen) similiar to the one visible when you use the volume control keys. Sadly, neither toasts nor notifications are sufficient for my needs.

I experimented a lot with `@android:style/Theme.Dialog`, but the dialogs it creates are mostly not in the foreground.

How do I create what I need or how is the always-foreground popup implemented in Android?

Comment: The volume popup is a toast but it is initiated by system code so i think it might have special permissions. Are you using it for debugging or a feature?

Comment: I want to use it for a feature. But to understand the whole matter, every solution would be fine for me. Is there a way to display modified toasts? Never heard of that before.

Comment: I'm going to try this. Seems to be the solution to my problem. [Creating a Custom Toast View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView) Man, i should really read the docs better! ;)